# Echo PHP Variable in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So for one of my messaging feature, I would like my mass-messages to be able to show the user's username.

This is the 'message' in my `message` for the `messages` table.

```
Hey $_SESSION['username']!

General message for everyone
```

However, when I tried placing '$_SESSION['username']' inside my mysql table, it doesn't echo the username on the message.

My messages are stored in the database and it basically echo's it out on the message page.

Can something like that be done?

Comment: you should better concatenate it with your message you get from database.

Comment: store some kind of tag like `Hey %USERNAME% ...` and replace before printing the message

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: @RC. the replacing idea sounds good and should work! But why is it that what I did doesn't work? Should it still print out the username?

Comment: `This is the 'message' in my message for the messages table.` <- Heh. This confused the hell outta me.

Comment: @user2488354 how is it saving in db, directly without ny concatenations ? save it in db by putting all concatenation dots and quotes

Comment: Because you are storing a text message with special characters, and when you do the echo, the PHP considers it as just that.

Comment: @user2488354 without seing your actual code/data it's hard to say

Comment: My actual code is just echoing out the content from my `messages` table.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to execute the stored code from a database value, you ll need to use `eval()`, which is `evil`. You might be better off storing a placeholder and then replace it with proper value before output.

**Store**

```
Hey #user#!

General message for everyone
```

**Display**

```
$output=str_replace("#user#",$_SESSION['username'],$yourContentFromDatabase);
echo $output;
```